# Access roles in nested group

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles, role-manager

I want to see if the current user is in the group "B_Group" (which this Group is in the Group "A_Group").

I used the code below:

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(@"A_Group\B_Group"))
```

but it does not find the user and returns false. also when I enumerate the roles of the user there is no such role for the user:

```
foreach( var role in Roles.GetRolesForUser())
```

it returns groups which are not in another group but does not return groups like B_Group.

Is there any solution for it?

tnx.

Comment: no, the user is only in group A, otherwise you will get two roles in foreach

Comment: @AnkushJain excuse me , it returns roles which are not in another group.

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP.  Can you retag, please?